# How to use innerHTML to print results into a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

So, this is my first post here:) I am a newbie programmer so I ran into a bit of a knot

I have a simple maths game where the user answers 10 questions and the results must be shown. At the beginning the user must enter his/her name and choose the difficulty level in a form. Once the questions are answered i want the results to be printed in a div tag inside the form itself. I used innerHTML but couldn't manage to do so.

I only made the function for the beginner level for simplicity.
Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maths Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p id="topic"><b>Maths Game</b></p>

    <hr></br>

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" 
     required></br></br>

    <label for="level">Game level</label>
    Beginner
    <input type="radio" name="level" value="beginner">
    Intermediate
    <input type="radio" name="level" value="intermediate">
    Advanced
    <input type="radio" name="level" value="advanced"></br></br>

    <p id="start"><button type="submit" onclick="confirmation();">Start 
    Quiz</button></p>

    <div id="results"></div>

</form>



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function beginnerQuestions(){
        var marks=0;
        function questions(){
            var marks=0;
            var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+1;
            var y=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)+1;
            var o=["+","-"];
            var q1=x+o[Math.floor(Math.random()*o.length)]+y;
            var ans=eval(q1).toFixed(1);
            var a1=prompt(q1+" is");
            if(eval(a1).toFixed(1)==ans){
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="</br>"+'<div 
            id="pass">'+'<img src="right.png" height="13" 
            width="13">'+q1+"="+a1+'</div>'

                marks=eval(marks+2);
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="</br>"+'<div 
            id="fail">'+'<img src="wrong.png" height="13" width="13">'+"Your 
            answer: "+a1+"  Correct answer: "+ans+'</div>');


            }
            return marks
        }


        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            questions();
        }

        if(marks<10){
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='<p id="high">'+" 
        </br>"+"</br>"+"Marks: "+marks+'</p>';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='<p id="low">'+" 
        </br>"+"</br>"+"Marks: "+marks+'</p>';

    }

    function confirmation(){
        var user=document.getElementById("name").value;

        var l=document.querySelector('input[name=level]:checked').value;

        confirm("Hello"+user+"!. You have chosen the "+l+" level for your 
        maths quiz. Is this correct? Please press OK to start or Cancel to 
        choose a different level of difficulty.")

        if(l="beginner"){
            beginnerQuestions();
        }
        if(l="intermediate"){
            intermediateQuestions();
        }
        if(l="advanced"){
            advancedQuestions();
        }
    }



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: = is assignment.... so `if(l="beginner"){` is wrong

Comment: We need more information. 

1 - The code really enter in the "if" with InnerHTML?
2 - The sintax of JavaScript is correct? (verify in the browser if the console show some error. if JS trhow some error, the code below doesnt execute.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? What results are you seeing?

Comment: You can use innerHTML, but you're calling question() multiple times and not concatenating the results.  Change it to "..innerHTML+=.."  Maybe that will help.

Comment: I wouldn't use `innerHTML` because it removes event handlers from `DOM elements. I would use `something like `appendChild`

Comment: it seems like you forgot to put `}` for your `else` statement

Comment: @Ryan  There were some js errors that I corrected. However, I want to print the results of the maths test to the div tag with id "Results" at the bottom of the form. The results consist of whether the answer to each question is right or wrong and the overall marks obtained. I just can't seem to get this using innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

I believe part of your problem comes from the way you've written your string following .innerHTML. For the second one, try with :

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "</br><div id='fail'><img src'wrong.png' height='13' width='13'>Your answer: "+a1+" Correct answer: "+ans+"</div>";
```

Same for your other .innerHTML strings. You only need to + sign when inserting variables, not between HTML Tags. Also, you should use " only when opening & closing part of the string and ' for attributes. Or the opposite.

You don't need to add a `)` at the end of the string.
Instead of `</br>`, you should be using `<br>`. And you are missing a closing tag at the end of your `beginnerQuestions()` function.

JSFiddle example :  https://jsfiddle.net/81wvm6h7/6/

Refs: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML
& https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Thank hexangel616 for your help. There were some js errors that I corrected. However, I want to print the results of the maths test to the div tag with id "Results" at the bottom of the form. The results consist of whether the answer to each question is right or wrong and the overall marks obtained. I just can't seem to get this using innerHTML. Hope I'm not troubling you.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/81wvm6h7/5/ and will edit my answer to add new details. The code in the fiddle works for displaying the answers in the div tag with the results id. That being said, it seems there are other problems in yourl code... and I would use <br> instead of </br> : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Between if you keep the `beginnerQuestions()` function, you need to add a closing tag after your last else state, just before your `confirmation()` function : https://jsfiddle.net/81wvm6h7/6/ I think the only problem now comes from the  `if(marks < 10){}else{}` statement.

Answer (score 0):

`if else` statement must have `open` and `close` curly bracket...

please check inside your `beginnerQuestions()` function:

```
if(marks<10){
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='<p id="high">'+" 
    </br>"+"</br>"+"Marks: "+marks+'</p>';
}else{
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML='<p id="low">'+" 
    </br>"+"</br>"+"Marks: "+marks+'</p>';
} //you forgot to put this line
```